# Database table design - parent child record spin off from main table?

Tags: database, parent-child

I have a table "person", implementing a field as 'SupervisorID'.

PersonID
PersionName
DOB
Address
SupervisorID

If SupervisorID field is empty or NULL means he/she is supervisor or no supervisor at all.

I am thinking of to spin off as separate table, eg. table 'supervisor' to indicate this parent-child relationship.

Table 'supervisor':
SupervisorID
PersonID

For those have no supervisor will not appear in this table.

Comment: Did you use Google? There are tons of solutions for your problem. This could you [starting point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design)

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you are trying to create a many-to-many relationship (that is: employee can have many/one/zero supervisors).

For simple one-to-many relationship the additional table is usually not needed, if it only contains (SupervisorID, PersonID). It becomes useful when a relationship has its own attributes. For example (SupervisorID, PersonID, DateStarted) would be useful to neatly store the additional attribute: date when employee-supervisor relation started.